# Adding Table Based Shipping Method

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

We are new to the shipping methods and have a question about using table rates

We have a test site at https://southernrecords.co.uk

We set the Table Rates up with Price V Destination
We have created a shipping csv file just with one record in it and uploaded it to the site
Country Region/State    Zip/Postal Code Order Subtotal (and above)  Shipping Price
GBR *   *   10  2

When we select the record under the Soul menu the price is £28
We add it to our basket and then proceed to the checkout were we fill in the required fields selecting United Kingdom as the country

The only shipping method displayed is fixed - flat rate

We thought the rules say if the Price is above £10 and the Destination is GBR (England) it should
display but it doesn't show

Any help would really be appreciated

Thanks
Rich

Comment: please make sure shipping is enabled.rules seems working.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Pawan
The table rates are enabled but nothing shows on the checkout - only Fixed / Flat Rate is showing at £5.00

Comment: Got it working now - think the csv was the issue - Thanks

Comment: glad to know it worked :)